# BeautifulSoup: Replace anchor text with text from another tag

Tags: html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract all links on a page and so far I'm able to get the links but the anchor text in the link doesn't provide any *relevant* information. That information is contained in another sibling tag.

This is the Html Layout:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
     <td>
        <h3>Driver with license E or F</h3>
        <div class = "date">..</div>
        <br>
        <p>...</p>
        <div id='print'>
        <a href="show_classifieds?..." class="bar">Go To Details</a>
        </div>
        <br>    
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <h3>Payroll Administrator</h3>
        <div class = "date">..</div>
        <br>
        <p>...</p>
        <div id='print'>
        <a href="show_classifieds?..." class="bar">Go To Details</a>
        </div>
        <br>    
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <h3>Head of Sales and Marketing</h3>
        <div class = "date">..</div>
        <br>
        <p>...</p>
        <div id='print'>
        <a href="show_classifieds?..." class="bar">Go To Details</a>
        </div>
        <br>    
   </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

When I extract the links, I get the following:

```
<a href="show_classifieds?..." class="bar">Go To Details</a>
<a href="show_classifieds?..." class="bar">Go To Details</a>
<a href="show_classifieds?..." class="bar">Go To Details</a>
```

But:

1. I'm interested in replacing the text **Go To Details** with the text in the  tag in each case.
2. These links will be displayed on an external website so I prefer them to be **absolute** instead of **relative**

hence in the end I'm hoping for something like these:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/show_classifieds?..." class="bar">Driver with license E or F</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/show_classifieds?..." class="bar">Payroll Administrator</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/show_classifieds?..." class="bar">Head of Sales and Marketing</a>
```

Any help will be gracefully appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give you a stable solution, you really need to make sure that all pages follow exactly the same pattern as your example.

***Basic Assumption:***

Assuming the text you want always resides in the `h3` tag which is the sibling of `div print`, who is the parent of the anchor link.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    # here is how you get the text from 'h3' tag
    header = a.parent.find_previous_sibling('h3').text
    # here is how you set the text of the anchor tag to be the text of 'h3' tag
    a.string = header
    print a
```

Further Reading:
[tag.string](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-string)

(You can use urljoin with the domain name to construct absolute urls if you want)
[urljoin](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin)

***Output***:

```
<a class="bar" href="show_classifieds?...">Driver with license E or F</a>
<a class="bar" href="show_classifieds?...">Payroll Administrator</a>
<a class="bar" href="show_classifieds?...">Head of Sales and Marketing</a>
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work..but I understand the part of making the url **absolute** so if you could revise ur code to show how I can get the _h3_ tag to be the anchor text, that would be great.

Comment: @maxcuban I changed the code as you mentioned. Let me know if you need more.