# Remove specific element from html page using lxml python etree

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I want to load the html contents of the page in an xml tree and remove the  elements in it using lxml in python. I just want to know how would I remove the  elements from the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the combination of `BeautifulSoup4` and `lxml` to reach your goal easily.

To parse your HTML into tree / soup. You just need to have all the ingredients installed and do.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """..."""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
...
```

You modify the tree, here is a whole list of references teaching you how to modify the contents/attribute of a tag etc.

[BeautifulSoup/Modify The tree](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-the-tree)

Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157186/beautifulsoup-replace-anchor-text-with-text-from-another-tag/20158286#20158286) I did to modify the contents of `anchor` tag